# Class not found in Php when trying to extends a class

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a plugin where i have to extends a class from another `php` file. But i am getting `Fatal error: Class 'EWWL_Admin_Init' not found`.

Here is my main file code.

```
class Eden_Woocommerce_WL_Admin {

    private static $instance = null;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (is_null(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->includes();
        $this->add_menu_page();
    }

    private function includes() {
        include_once( EWCWL_PLUGIN_DIR . '/includes/admin/ewwl-admin-menu.php' );
        include_once( EWCWL_PLUGIN_DIR . '/includes/admin/ewwl-admin-init.php' );
    }

    private function add_menu_page() {
        EWWL_Admin_Init::getInstance();
        EWCWL_Admin_menu::getInstance();
    }
}
```

here is `EWCWL_Admin_menu` class

```
class EWCWL_Admin_menu extends EWWL_Admin_Init {

    private static $instance = null;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(is_null(self::$instance)){
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
    }

    public function __construct($args = array()) {

        if (!empty($args)) {
            $this->settings = $args;

            if (isset($this->settings['create_menu_page']) && $this->settings['create_menu_page']) {
                add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_ewwl_menu_page'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function add_ewwl_menu_page() {
        $position = apply_filters('ewcwl_plugins_menu_item_position', '62.32');
        add_menu_page('plugin_panel', __('Menu title', 'ed-wcwl'), 'manage_options', 'ed_plugin_panel', NULL, '', $position);
    }

}
```

Here is `EWWL_Admin_Init` class

```
class EWWL_Admin_Init {

    private static $instance = null;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if( is_null(self::$instance) ){
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {

    }

}
```

May be i am missing something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you properly define plugin name ? in comments ?

Comment: @Noman Yeah, i did it. Other functionality working fine. Got stuck on this point.

Comment: Did you include/use the file that contains that class before trying to extend it?

Comment: Yeah I included it before extends it. Please see the class `Eden_Woocommerce_WL_Admin`

Answer (score 0):

It happened because `EWWL_Admin_Init` didn't included before `EWCWL_Admin_menu`. Swapping two lines

```
include_once( EWCWL_PLUGIN_DIR . '/includes/admin/ewwl-admin-init.php' );
include_once( EWCWL_PLUGIN_DIR . '/includes/admin/ewwl-admin-menu.php' );
```

from `Eden_Woocommerce_WL_Admin` class solved the issue.